# XCode skeleton projects overriding

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm pretty new to Objective-C, so I am not entirely sure of the terms I should be searching for. Apologies if you've seen this question before.

I have noticed that in the skeleton projects that XCode produces contain overrides like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I am not sure why this is part of the code that is generated. I am confident that I could omit this method and not affect the application because it simply calls the method on the parent class. Is this method stub just here to show the developer that they can override this commonly overridden method, or is this something in Objective-C that I have not yet come across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a method that you'll often want to override, so it's included in the template as a convenience. If you don't add any code of your own to it, you could as well remove it altogether because only calling super is the same as leaving it out.

I suspect it's also included to remind you that you have to call super if you override it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have nothing to add to this method it could be left out.  It is there to provide you a template where you can add your code for things you want done in viewDidLoad.